# pyCrypto importing only "crypto", not "Crypto" (not found)

Tags: python-2.7, pip, pycrypto

I'm using python 2.7 and tried installing the pyCrypto module using pip (`pip install pycrypto`) which downloaded and installed the 2.6 version, as it is needed for using twisted.

However, whenever I try to use it, I get an `ImportError` saying that the module `Crypto` doesn't exist - but I can import `crypto` normally.

I already tried uninstalling and installing it again, but still didn't work.

Is there any bug in the package downloaded using pip or is it anything else I'm doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone is having this same problem, the reason was that I had mistakenlly installed the package `crypto` before installing `pycrypto`. Once I removed both packages and reinstalled `pycrypto` everything worked.

I believe that it might be related to Windows treating `crypto` and `Crypto` folders as the same.